# Code to filter data where observations may or may not be present in the dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make a template of code to filter data. The problem I am having is that there are various levels of categorical data and if I use the dplyr function filter R returns no data if the filtering level was not in the data.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

lease   <-c(1,2,1)
year<-c(2010,2011,2010)
beg <-c(1,2,1)
gas<-c(1,2,2)
pelelts<-c(1,2,2)
df<-data.frame(lease, year, beg, gas, pelelts)

df%>%
 mutate_all(as.character)%>%
 filter(lease==1 | year==2010)%>%
 filter(beg==1 & gas==2)%>%
 filter(pelelts==3)
```

this returns
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names), which I believe is because pelelts==3 doesn't exist (and I get data if I remove this line of code). The problem I have is I don't want to check every data set for what is there as it will vary on a subset by subset basis. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Would my code look something like this:                   df%>%
  mutate_all(as.character)%>%
  filter(lease==1 | year==2010)%>%
  filter(beg==1 & gas==2)%>%
  if(pelelts==3){
    include in dataframe
  }else
    ignore pelelts I know include and ignore aren't R syntax as such I am a little stuck on this one @H5470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying `pelelts == 3` you're telling R that you *only* want 3. You need to modify your code to catch the other conditions that are acceptable. If 3 doesn't exist then *something else* has to happen, or no results will be returned.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense but not quite sure how to code that. Would I use if else or similar?

Answer (score 0):

This code got the required result thanks @H5470

```
df%>%
mutate_all(as.character)%>%
filter(lease==1 | year==2010)%>%
filter(beg==1 & gas==2)%>%
mutate(pelelts=case_when(pelelts %in% '3'~ '3',
                       pelelts %in% c('0', '1', '2')~ '',
                       TRUE~as.character(pelelts)))
```

returning:

```
lease year beg gas pelelts
   1 2010   1   2
```